# extract text from web page with vba after changing the page

Tags: html, database, excel, vba, web

I have to extract data from a web database with VBA, to do that there is a page web, where we can put the tag (that we can choose) and see the data saved (the web page : appinvtinywebdb.appspot.com/getvalue)
Now, I made a VBA macro (the code below) to access to the web page, write in the input text the proper tag and click on submit button, and i can see the data (on string form) on the web navigator

THE PROBLEM is when i want to copy the String to VBA (extract it) the code give me sentences and strings from the previous web page (which keep the same URL)
how can i read the new page pls?

```
Sub Lancer_Edoc()
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim MyStr As String

Set ie = New InternetExplorer

ie.Navigate2 "http://appinvtinywebdb.appspot.com/getvalue"

While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
   DoEvents
Wend

ie.Visible = True

Dim htmldoc As HTMLDocument
Dim htmlForms As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim htmlForm As HTMLFormElement
Dim HtmlElementStandard As HTMLGenericElement
Dim LeTexteExtrait As String

' Set htmldoc = ie.document
' obtient collection des formulaire de la page
'Set htmlForms = htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("tag")
' référence le formulaire de login
'Set htmlForm = htmlForms.namedItem("frmLogin")
' remplit les cases
Set oDoc = ie.document
' Valeur recherchée
oDoc.getElementsByName("tag")(0).Value = "trait"
oDoc.getElementsByTagName("form")(0).submit
'Allons chercher ce texte dans notre Item46
Dim iet As New InternetExplorer

Set htmldoc = ie.document

Set HtmlElementStandard = htmldoc.body.all(0)

'On le place dans notre variable prévue à cet effet
LeTexteExtrait = HtmlElementStandard.innerText
'On affiche le texte
MsgBox LeTexteExtrait, Title:="Le texte extrait de la page"

End Sub
```

Thank you !! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for direct connection instead of using IE:

```
Private Sub ConnectAndSubmitValue

Dim oHTTP As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
Dim URL As String
Dim res As String
Dim resHTML As HTMLDocument
Dim YOURTEXT as string

YOURTEXT = EncodeUrl("I ENTERED THIS TEXT")

Set resHTML = New HTMLDocument
Set oHTTP = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
    URL = "http://appinvtinywebdb.appspot.com/getvalue"
    res = "tag=" & YOURTEXT & "&fmt=html"

    With oHTTP
        .Open "POST", URL, False
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .Send (res)

        res = .responseText
        resHTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

End Sub
```

This will give you `res` as the entire html document in a string and a `resHTML` html document to manipulate as you like.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.
I just have a problem , " EncodeUrl is not defined " in my program , do i need a specific library

Comment: i ve used a "encoder url" fonction that i found on internet.
the output "res" is in a strange format : 

["VALUE", "", "\"sbj:\uc131\ubc31\uc9c4:\uc5ec\uac00:\ub09a\uc2dc:\uc704\ub3c4: 37.48062,\uacbd\ub3c4: 126.85918:0\""]

How can i convert that to text??

Thank you :)